# I moved all the CSS for my nav bar to it's own file and no the JS code no longer works wall my HTML files

Tags: javascript, html, css

I recently moved all the CSS code for my navbar into it's own file so that I can call on it for every page that needs it.

For some reason after doing so the JS code no longer works on all pages and only somewhat on the index.HTML page. The JS code is supposed to show a "go to top button" when scrolling down but the button shows up when first then when scrolling it disappears when reappears a second later. On all the other pages it all remains as a fixed element that does not move. The navbar is also supposed to change color as well.

Below is the code for the index.html

```html
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/nav.css">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat:500,700,900&display=swap" rel="stylesheet" />
  <link href="http://fonts.cdnfonts.com/css/the-scientist" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.13.1/css/all.min.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/magnific-popup.js/1.1.0/magnific-popup.min.css" />
  <link href="https://unpkg.com/aos@2.3.1/dist/aos.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="icon" href="images/FUJI RED MOUNTAIN.png">
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/magnific-popup.js/1.1.0/jquery.magnific-popup.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/scrollreveal@4.0.6/dist/scrollreveal.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/aos@2.3.1/dist/aos.js"></script>
  <script src="js/scripts.js"></script>

  <title>Index HTML</title>
</head>
<body>
<!--Navbar-->
  <form action="#" id="formData">
  </form>
  <nav class="navbar">
    <div class="inner-width">
      <a href="/" class="logo"></a>
      <button class="menu-toggle">
        <span></span>
        <span></span>
        <span></span>
      </button>
      <div class="navbar-menu">
        <a href="#home">Home</a>
        <a href="#about">About</a>
        <a href="#products">Products</a>
        <a href="#services">Services</a>
        <a href="#training">Training & Support</a>
        <a href="#contact">Contact Us</a>
        <a href="careers.html">Careers </a>
        <div class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="dropbtn">Log-in</a>
          <div class="dropdown-content">
            <h4>Account Number</h4>
            <form action="#">
              <input type="text" class="acctNum" placeholder="Account Number" />
              <h4>Password</h4>
              <input type="text" class="passWord" placeholder="Password" />
              <input type="submit" value="Log in" class="login" />
              <input type="button" onclick=" window.location='reg.html';" value="Create an Account" class="register" />
            </form>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    </div>
  </nav>

<!--Back to top-->
  <button class="goTop fas fa-arrow-up"></button>
  <script>
    AOS.init();
  </script>
<body>
```

Here is another page that the JS code does not work for at all.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/careerStyle.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/nav.css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat:500,700,900&display=swap" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link rel="icon" href="images/FUJI RED MOUNTAIN.png">
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/scripts.js"></script>
    <title>Fuji Dental Lab Careers</title>
  </head>

  <body>

    <!--Navbar-->
    <form action="#" id="formData">
    </form>
    <nav class="navbar">
      <div class="inner-width">
        <a href="/" class="logo"></a>
        <button class="menu-toggle">
          <span></span>
          <span></span>
          <span></span>
        </button>
        <div class="navbar-menu" id="cNavbar-menu">
          <a href="/index.html">Home</a>
          <div class="dropdown">
            <a href="#" class="dropbtn">Log-in</a>
            <div class="dropdown-content">
              <h4>Account Name</h4>
              <form action="#">
                <input type="text" class="acctNum" placeholder="Account Number" />
                <h4>Password</h4>
                <input type="text" class="passWord" placeholder="Password" />
                <input type="submit" value="Log in" class="login" />
                <input type="button" onclick=" window.location='reg.html';" value="Create an Account" class="register" />
              </form>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      
      </div>
      
    </nav>
    <section id="careers">
      <div class="cContainer">
        <h3 id="cTitle">Careers</h3>
        <a class="jTitle" href="cUpload.html">something something </a>
        <p>Los Angeles, CA</p>
        <span class="disc">something something something something something something something something something something something something something something something something something something something something something something something something something something something something something something something something something something something something something something something something</span>
        <a class="jTitle" href="cUpload.html">something something </a>
        <p>Dallas, TX</p>
        <span class="disc">something something something something something something something something something something something something something something something something something something something something something something  <br> <br>
          <p id="bold">something something </p>
        </span>
        <a class="jTitle" href="cUpload.html">something something </a>
        <p>Dallas, TX</p>
        <span class="disc">something something something something something something something something something something something something something something something something something something something something something something something something something something <br>something something something something something something 
        </span>
        <a class="jTitle" href="cUpload.html">something something </a>
        <p>Dallas, TX</p>
        <span class="disc">something something something something something something something something something something something something something something something something something something</span>
      </div>
    </section>

    <!--Back to top-->
    <button class="goTop fas fa-arrow-up"></button>
    <script>
      AOS.init();
    </script>

  </body>

</html>
```

Below is the CSS file I moved from my main CSS page to it's own.

```css
.navbar {
  position: fixed;
  background-color: transparent;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 30px 0;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 999;
  transition: 0.3s linear;
}

.inner-width {
  max-width: 1300px;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 0 20px;
}

.navbar .inner-width {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.logo {
  width: 500px;
  height: 44px;
  background-image: url(../images/Full\ Logo\ white.png);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: contain;
  z-index: 9999;
}

.menu-toggle {
  background: none;
  width: 30px;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  position: relative;
  outline: none;
  z-index: 999;
  display: none;
}

.menu-toggle span {
  display: block;
  height: 3px;
  background-color: #fff;
  margin: 6px 0;
  position: relative;
  transition: 0.3s linear;
}

.navbar-menu a {
  color: #f1f1f1;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-weight: 500;
  margin-left: 20px;
  transition: 0.2s linear;
}

.navbar-menu a:hover {
  color: #d03228 !important;
}

.sticky {
  background-color: #fff;
  padding: 18px 0;
}

.sticky .logo {
  background-image: url(../images/Full\ Logo\ black.png);
}

.sticky .navbar-menu a {
  color: #111;
}

.sticky .menu-toggle span {
  background-color: #111;
}


/* Dropdown Button */

.dropbtn {
  background-color: transparent;
  color: white;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 15px;
  border: none;
  top: 0;
}

.dropdown {
  position: absolute;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 10%;
}

.dropdown-content {
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-left: -100px;
  padding: 10px;
  display: none;
  position: relative;
  background-color: #353b48;
  min-width: 160px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown-content h4 {
  color: white;
  padding: 5px 0 5px 0;
}

.dropdown-content .login {
  margin-top: 15px;
  background-color: transparent;
  color: #f1f1f1;
  font-size: 16px;
  border: 2px solid #d03228;
  border-radius: 10px;
  padding: 5px;
  margin-left: auto;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: 0.3s linear;
}

.dropdown-content .login:hover {
  background-color: #d03228;
  color: #fff;
}

.dropdown-content .register {
  margin-top: 10px;
  background-color: transparent;
  color: #f1f1f1;
  font-size: 16px;
  border: 2px solid #d03228;
  border-radius: 10px;
  padding: 5px;
  margin-left: auto;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: 0.3s linear;
}

.dropdown-content .register:hover {
  background-color: #d03228;
  color: #fff;
}


/* Show the dropdown menu on hover */

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
}

.goTop {
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 999;
  bottom: 40px;
  right: 40px;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  background-color: #d03228;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 6px;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: #fff;
  outline: none;
  display: none;
}
```

Here is the JS code that is supposed to work across all pages when called on. It is supposed make "go To Top" button appear and make the navbar change color when scrolling down.

```js
var form = document.getElementById('formData');

form.addEventListener("submit", handleSubmit)
$(window).scroll(function() {
  if (this.scrollY > 20) {
    $(".navbar").addClass("sticky");
    $(".goTop").fadeIn();
  } else {
    $(".navbar").removeClass("sticky");
    $(".goTop").fadeOut();
  }
});

$(".goTop").click(function() {
  scroll(0, 0);
});

$(".menu-toggle").click(function() {
  $(this).toggleClass("active");
  $(".navbar-menu").toggleClass("active");
});
```

So in summary my JS code no longer works across all pages after I moved my CSS code for the NAVBAR into it's own file. I'm trying to get it to work on any page that calls on it.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Link the script src tag in the head of your HTML? What is the JS File named

Comment: Yes. <script src="js/scripts.js"></script>

JS file is named  scripts.js

Comment: You have to move `script.js` to the end of the html file just before the closing body tag...

Comment: and you have a closing div tag too much in both html files

Comment: Although those are errors they have no effect on the issue. So i moved the script to the end and nothing has changed. I think it has something to do with moving the CSS as the JS code did work previously before the move.

Comment: Ok i've spent the last day trying to look at solutions and nothing is working. Commenting to keep the thread open since i can't ask again.